# Image (Error) reduce.median: Can't apply calendarRange filter to objects without a timestamp

Tags: google-earth-engine, javascript, sentinel-2

I tried illumination correction on Sentinel-2 images and obtain monthly median images.

However, I'm struggling with the following error:
`Image (Error) reduce.median: Can't apply calendarRange filter to objects without a timestamp.`

Could you look at my code and help me.

I tried these two methods.

```
return img_plus_ic.set('system:time_start',img.get('system:time_start'));

return img_plus_ic.copyProperties(img);
```

But they did not work.

Full code below (Also here, https://code.earthengine.google.com/c3a6647a1013ffcebcbe750ac7b07a5a)

```
var roi = ee.Geometry.Polygon([[[-115.51858045584667, 45.29650713146457],
          [-115.51858045584667, 44.2632748294202],
          [-113.60146619803417, 44.2632748294202],
          [-113.60146619803417, 45.29650713146457]]], null, false);
Map.centerObject(roi);
Map.addLayer(roi);



function cloud_mask(image) {
  var qa = image.select('QA60');
  var cloudBitMask = 1 << 10;
  var cirrusBitMask = 1 << 11;
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0).and(
             qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0));
  var out = image.updateMask(mask).divide(10000)
      .select("B.*")
      .copyProperties(image);
  return out;
  }
  
var dem = ee.Image("USGS/SRTMGL1_003");

function topoCorr_IC(img){

  // Extract image metadata about solar position
  var SZ_rad = ee.Image.constant(ee.Number(img.get('MEAN_SOLAR_ZENITH_ANGLE'))).multiply(3.14159265359).divide(180).clip(img.geometry().buffer(10000)); 
  var SA_rad = ee.Image.constant(ee.Number(img.get('MEAN_SOLAR_AZIMUTH_ANGLE')).multiply(3.14159265359).divide(180)).clip(img.geometry().buffer(10000)); 
  // Creat terrain layers
  var slp = ee.Terrain.slope(dem).clip(img.geometry().buffer(10000));
  var slp_rad = ee.Terrain.slope(dem).multiply(3.14159265359).divide(180).clip(img.geometry().buffer(10000));
  var asp_rad = ee.Terrain.aspect(dem).multiply(3.14159265359).divide(180).clip(img.geometry().buffer(10000));

  // Calculate the Illumination Condition (IC)
  // slope part of the illumination condition
  var cosZ = SZ_rad.cos();
  var cosS = slp_rad.cos();
  var slope_illumination = cosS.expression("cosZ * cosS", 
                                          {'cosZ': cosZ,
                                           'cosS': cosS.select('slope')});
  // aspect part of the illumination condition
  var sinZ = SZ_rad.sin(); 
  var sinS = slp_rad.sin();
  var cosAziDiff = (SA_rad.subtract(asp_rad)).cos();
  var aspect_illumination = sinZ.expression("sinZ * sinS * cosAziDiff", 
                                           {'sinZ': sinZ,
                                            'sinS': sinS,
                                            'cosAziDiff': cosAziDiff});
  // full illumination condition (IC)
  var ic = slope_illumination.add(aspect_illumination);

  // Add IC to original image
  var img_plus_ic = ee.Image(img.addBands(ic.rename('IC')).addBands(cosZ.rename('cosZ')).addBands(cosS.rename('cosS')).addBands(slp.rename('slope')));
  return img_plus_ic.copyProperties(img, ["system:time_start"]);
}

var S2 = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2")
                              .filterDate("2019-01-01", "2019-12-31")
                              .filterBounds(roi)
                              .map(cloud_mask)
                              .map(topoCorr_IC);


var m1 = S2.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(1, 31, 'day_of_year')).median();

print (m1);
```

`Image (Error) reduce.median: Can't apply calendarRange filter to objects without a timestamp.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cloud masking, at line 18, is discarding the system:time_start property (by default system properties aren't copied).  Add another copy_properties to catch it:

```
var out = image.updateMask(mask).divide(10000)
    .select("B.*")
    .copyProperties(image)
    .copyProperties(image, ["system:time_start"])
```

or better, just replace the bands in the original image with the scaled ones and don't fiddle with properties at all:

```
function cloud_mask(image) {
  var qa = image.select('QA60')
  var cloudBitMask = 1 << 10
  var cirrusBitMask = 1 << 11
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0).and(
             qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0))
  var scaled = image.select("B.*").updateMask(mask).divide(10000)
  return image.addBands(scaled, null, true)
}
```